Why I am getting this error I tried reinstalling dependencies but to no avail
Cant seem to find a solution to this Visual studio
I tried reinstalling dependencies but it still didn't work
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~4.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^21.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^21.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^21.6.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^7.0.6",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "expo": "^52.0.11",
    "firebase": "^11.0.2",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.20.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~4.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.13",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "~18.3.12",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.8",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}


These are my dependencies installed. I tried CHATGPT but the solutions offered did not fix my problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please confirm that you have add the react-native-dotenv plugin in the babel.config.js file.
